# Get keys From Interface

Tags: mongodb, go

I know the title says interface array, but that's how the data is being printed.

I have a field in mongodb called "devices" which is of type object. This object contains a bunch of random key values pairs. The keys are just randomly generated integers and the value are a string.

So I've written some code which retrieves the data from the db, after I've retrieved the data I want to get all the keys from theses objects and store them in an array and I can't seem to figure out how to do that.

First I assume my issue lies with the way I'm getting the data since I'm storing it into an interface{} and not an array. The data prints out like an array but when I change the structure to retrieve an array it comes back empty so I scrapped that idea.

**Function**

```
    type Data struct {
        Devices interface{} `json:"devices" bson:"devices"`
    }

    client := db.ConnectClient()

    col := client.Database("Users").Collection("User")

    var deviceIds Data

    _ = col.FindOne(context.TODO(), bson.D{}).Decode(&deviceIds)

    log.Print(deviceIds.Devices)
```

**Output**

```
2020/10/29 21:28:07 [{123456789 Plant} {456753121 Money Bringer} {798745321 Hello}]
```

Also I have tried changing that struct to

```
    type Data struct {
        Devices map[int]interface{} `json:"devices" bson:"devices"`
    }
```

which gives an output of

```
2020/10/29 21:35:10 map[123456789:Plant 456753121:Money Bringer 798745321:Hello]
```

but again I don't know how to extract the keys from them

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So as I just finished writing this question I figured out the map was the correct way to get my data.

Posted the question and answering it myself because I thought it would be useful for others

```
type Data struct {
        Devices map[int]interface{} `json:"devices" bson:"devices"`
}


for key, value := range deviceIds.Devices {
        fmt.Println(key, value)
}
```

Changing the struct to the above map and then looping through it with range worked perfectly